# How can I add taggit tags to a newly created Django model instance?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm unable to add Taggit tags to a newly created Django model instance from within a DRF serializer.

When attempting to do use the new instance, the operation fails with `list object has no attribute add`.

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # fails with `list object has no attribute add`
        thing = Thing.objects.create(**validated_data)
        custom_tags = validated_data.pop("custom_tags", [])
        for custom_tag in custom_tags:
            thing.custom_tags.add(
                custom_tag.pop("name"), tag_kwargs=custom_tag
            )
        thing.save()

    def create_with_hack(self, validated_data):
        # works after fetching the record from DB
        thing = Thing.objects.create(**validated_data)
        thing_ = Thing.objects.get(pk=thing.id)
        custom_tags = validated_data.pop("custom_tags", [])
        for custom_tag in custom_tags:
            thing_.custom_tags.add(
                custom_tag.pop("name"), tag_kwargs=custom_tag
            )
        thing_.save()
```

As noted above, I'm able to work around this by first explicitly fetching record from the database but that is undesirable. Also, the `refresh_from_db` model method does not solve the problem.

Environment:

- Python 3.8
- Django 4.2.2
- Taggit 4.0.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the entire error message. Also indicate which line of code where the error occurs. And please add the `Thing` class.

Comment: Please provide model definition for Thing.